# Invoke another class's method, passing object name as argument

Tags: java

New to Java, trying to code a basic traffic simulation where I have an Intersection class and an SimEngine (event list) class.

My Intersection class has a method called Arrival() indicating that a car has arrived at the intersection.  As part of the method, I want to schedule a departure for that car at a timestamp 3 seconds later using the schedule() method in SimEngine.

The schedule() method takes four arguments: (What we're scheduling, the vehicle ID, the Intersection id, the timestamp).  My question is about passing the Intersection id (this simulation has multiple intersections).  If I don't know the name of the Intersection object's reference variable, how can I pass it to another function?

Comment: Maybe reconsider your design if you want references you don't have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the vehicles in your system first -- a common choice, especially in database driven applications, is to use a integer value. So attach an unique identifier to each of your vehicles, and then reference to them as an `Integer` or `Long`, depending on how many instances you foresee.

If you only hold the data in the memory, you can store and retrieve the vehicles from a `Map<Integer,Vehicle>`. Take extra precautions on thread safety here, `ConcurrentHashMap` is a good choice.